# regex not working as expected in grep

Tags: regex, grep

My problem is about a regex. Thanks to `regexr`, I managed to [write up an expression](http://regexr.com/39r9i) that matches the interface name `route` linux command gave me.

But I can't catch it with:

```
route | grep -Eo "(?:((\w|\.|\*)+\s+)){7}([^ .]+[0-9]+)$"
```

Why is that?

Comment: There are a bunch of different regex dialects. `grep -E` and JavaScript (`regexr`'s dialect, from a quick look) don't use the exact same one, so you can only use the regexr output as a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different programs (and different versions of said program) might use different regex implementations. Try reducing or breaking down your regex part by part to know which feature is supported/is not supported.

For example, I need to remove the *non-capturing group* specifier `?:` from your example so that my *GNU grep* can run as expected in Solaris 11.

Or you can try to replace `-E` with `-P` to use [Perl regex engine](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#grep-Programs) which, in my case, make my *GNU grep* able to run your regex without further modifications.

```
route | grep -Po "(?:((\w|\.|\*)+\s+)){7}([^ .]+[0-9]+)$"
```

**Note:** *GNU grep* in Solaris 11 is located in `/usr/gnu/bin/grep`